# How to change or reorder vertex id

Tags: maya

I hope the vertex ID is sequential.
Idk how to do it.

[image]

Comment: You cannot have a vertex whose number is superior to the total number of vertices on the mesh since Maya use it to build the mesh topology.

Answer (score 0):

You could, if you really wanted to, rebuild the entire mesh using the same vert positions in some order other than the one you get from Maya. However I would recommend not trying; the vertex order is basically arbitrary and there are many different thing you can do while working with a mesh to cause them to re-order.  Maya isn't built around the idea of stable vertex IDs -- it's a persistent problem -- but overcoming it is a major hassle and will always be fragile.

Maybe you can describe the problem you're trying to solve and we can figure out way to approach it using a less troublesome approach?